# Angular 4.2.6 CLI generated component is never rendered

Tags: java, spring, angular, typescript, jhipster

I started a new JHipster project. I have used angular 2 before but I can't figure out why none of my new components are showing.

Using Angular v4.2.6

I did the following:

- Create application with jhipster
- Create a new component using CLI

Result:

**rahan.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-rahan',
  templateUrl: './rahan.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class RahanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**rahan.component.html**

```
<p>
    rahan works!
</p>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <jhi-rahan></jhi-rahan>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
declarations: [
    ...,
    RahanComponent
```

I can see it if I inspect other elements like this: `<jhi-file-upload></jhi-file-upload>` but it has no child elements and it's never rendered.

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any idea what?

Comment: Your code looks fine so far...how is home.component.html imported to app.component.html?

Comment: @SimonBriggs I guess it's imported through `router-outlet`,  `RouterModule.forRoot([ HOME_ROUTE ], { useHash: true })` because there's no direct import. But I can see my component when I inspect element so I don't think it matters. It's just that the component is empty and has size 0.

Comment: Hi @VladTopala, have you solved this problem? I'm facing the same issue with jhipster 4.14.1 and angular